# Where can I access there ASP.NET Application Cache from Global Application_Start?

Tags: asp.net, caching

Can I access the ASP.NET Cache object from Application_Start?  I was previously using it in a page render.  I though it might be available as an object under the 'Server' object but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HttpRuntime.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx).