# How can I locate .NET Library property/function that return a particular type?

Tags: .net

Occasionally I will know that there is a .NET Framework function that returns a particular type of object, but I can't recall the property or function name.  It would be really nice to be able to somehow scan the Framework or other DLL for functions that return a particular type of object.  (For example, it would have helped when I asked **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722360/where-can-i-access-there-asp-net-application-cache-from-global-application-start)**, and I have a similar question again.)

Can anyone suggest how I might do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/) will help with this. Search for and select your type (F3) and use Analyze (Ctrl+R) on it. Then expand the **Used By** node.

You'll still need to narrow things down from this list, but it gives a good start.

**Edit:** Actually, you get **Exposed By** and **Instantiated By** nodes as well, so among those options I think you are covered.

Comment: ExposedBy is what I was looking for...  Thanks!